# Spring-Boot Server is not running, hangs after Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, dispatcher

After running the spring-boot App, I'm getting the below logs:

Using below:

1. Kubernetes
2. Bit-Bucket Pipeline
3. MySQL and Oracle
4. Consul
5. Running Debug Mode

> 2019-07-17 10:33:03 [0] [main] INFO  c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
>   2019-07-17 10:33:11 [0] [http-nio-9080-exec-2] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'